# Firebase Cloud Messaging suddenly returns 401

Tags: java, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a really confusing issue. I'm setting up an Admin app that would use `Firebase Cloud Messaging` to send a **push notification** to the target client. It was working for a while, and then it suddenly stopped working and I made no changes to the code - that's the confusing part!

Here is the Firebase Configuration.

**FirebaseConfiguration.java**

```
@Configuration
public class FirebaseConfig {

    private final String databaseUrl;

    private final String configPath;

    @Inject
    public FirebaseConfig(
            @Value("${firebase.database.url}") String databaseUrl, 
            @Value("${firebase.config.path}") String configPath) {
        this.databaseUrl = databaseUrl;
        this.configPath = configPath;
    }

    @Bean
    public DatabaseReference firebaseDatabase() {
        return FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {
        /*
         * https://firebase.google.com/docs/admin/setup Create service account; Download .json config file
         */
        final InputStream serviceAccount = FirebaseConfig.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(configPath);

        final FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredentials(GoogleCredentials.fromStream(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl(databaseUrl)
                .build();

        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
    }
}
```

Here, the `configPath` is the path to the `.json` file with all the configuration of my Firebase application, generated in the Firebase console of my application.

**myapp-firebase-config.json**

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "myapp",
  "private_key_id": "8564e07po7cff976068c702dcdpodbbb0cu3e6",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----...\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "firebase-adminsdk-jo9yp@myapp.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "12345",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/firebase-adminsdk-jo9yp%myapp.iam.gserviceaccount.com"
}
```

And now the code that is trying to send the push notification, but is failing.

```
Message message = Message.builder()
                .putData("Message", "Test 123")
                .setToken(token)
                .build();

        ApiFuture<String> response = FirebaseMessaging.getInstance().sendAsync(message);
        final String result = response.get(); // throws the exception
```

The stack trace of the exception that is being thrown goes like this:

```
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.firebase.tasks.Tasks.getResultOrThrowExecutionException(Tasks.java:179)
    at com.google.firebase.tasks.Tasks.await(Tasks.java:102)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.TaskToApiFuture.get(TaskToApiFuture.java:74)
    at com.newfaces.businesslogic.logic.MessageRequestLogicBean$1.run(MessageRequestLogicBean.java:75)
    at com.google.firebase.internal.TaskToApiFuture$1.onComplete(TaskToApiFuture.java:50)
    at com.google.firebase.tasks.OnCompleteCompletionListener$1.run(OnCompleteCompletionListener.java:54)
    at com.google.common.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$DirectExecutor.execute(MoreExecutors.java:399)
    at com.google.firebase.tasks.OnCompleteCompletionListener.onComplete(OnCompleteCompletionListener.java:48)
    at com.google.firebase.tasks.TaskCompletionListenerQueue.flush(TaskCompletionListenerQueue.java:81)
    at com.google.firebase.tasks.TaskImpl.setException(TaskImpl.java:115)
    at com.google.firebase.tasks.Tasks$1.run(Tasks.java:84)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.api.client.repackaged.com.google.common.base.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:213)
    at com.google.api.client.util.Preconditions.checkNotNull(Preconditions.java:127)
    at com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory.createJsonParser(JacksonFactory.java:98)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.handleSendHttpError(FirebaseMessaging.java:251)
    at com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessaging.makeSendRequest(FirebaseMessaging.java:238)
```

I found the root code segment that throws this exception in `FirebaseMessaging` class:

```
  private void handleSendHttpError(HttpResponseException e) throws FirebaseMessagingException {
    MessagingServiceErrorResponse response = new MessagingServiceErrorResponse();
    try {
      JsonParser parser = jsonFactory.createJsonParser(e.getContent()); // HERE e.getContent() == null which throws the NullPointerException
      parser.parseAndClose(response);
    } catch (IOException ignored) {
      // ignored
    }

    String code = FCM_ERROR_CODES.get(response.getString("status"));
    if (code == null) {
      code = UNKNOWN_ERROR;
    }
    String msg = response.getString("message");
    if (Strings.isNullOrEmpty(msg)) {
      msg = String.format("Unexpected HTTP response with status: %d; body: %s",
          e.getStatusCode(), e.getContent());
    }
    throw new FirebaseMessagingException(code, msg, e);
  }
```

Now, given that this doesn't actually return the exception, it's impossible to debug, but I looked at my `Firebase API Metrics` and found out that the server was returning error codes `401 - Unauthorized`. So in order to verify that, I made a `curl` like this, as per https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/http#checkAPIkey:

```
# server_key=YOUR_SERVER_KEY

# curl --header "Authorization: key=$server_key" \
       --header Content-Type:"application/json" \
       https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send \
       -d "{\"registration_ids\":[\"ABC\"]}"
```

And the response I got was this:

```
{"multicast_id":6706957967213497648,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":[{"message_id":"0:1532214216265421%fa1b6a1df9fd7ecd"}]}
```

... indicating that the request was Authorized for the given server_key and registration_token (registration_id) that I was using from the application.

That leaves me totally lost. Because the same token gets Unathorized from the app, yet it's perfectly Authorized when `curl`ed. I don't know how to proceed with this, any help is greatly appreciated.

### EDIT

Just to mention that I also tried running in the `dryRun` mode which worked.

Comment: I have limited experience with this but suspect that your curl test is not meaningful because it is not for the  [HTTP v1 API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/migrate-v1).  It looks like a [test of the Legacy API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/auth-server#authorize_http_requests) with a GCM endpoint instead of the Firebase endpoint, [https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)

Comment: @BobSnyder Seems like you're right. I tried with v1 API now, it works again - but I can't see the request in the console dashboard so it's dubious where it actually went.

Comment: Any luck with this?

Comment: @wesleyy I am facing similar issue, have you found solution?